# Changing the eccentricity of a vertex from $5$ to $4$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, geometric-construction

Can anyone help me in changing the eccentricity of any vertex from $5$ to $4$, lying on the outer circle, so that only one vertex is with eccentricity $4$ and rest of the vertices have eccentricity $5$? In the following figure eccentricity of every vertex is five. Any kind of help or hint will be of great help to me. Thanks a lot for your kind attention and help.

PS : **Any other figure is also welcome on 14 vertices**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Draw an edge from $13$ to $8$. The eccentricity for $1$ decreased to $4$, as the distance from $1$ to $6$ is $4$.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I just edited the question. Can you have a look again?

Comment: Ahh, I missed that you only want to change the eccentricity for one vertex. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.